# Connecting and disconnecting from Mysql continuously with Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, connection

Newbie question....sorry

I have a simple mysql database running in our Intranet (windows server) which >20 people connect to for searching/inserting records, etc
This is done with a simple Excel GUI.

Process is:

- Search Strings are typed in excel cells
- VBA opens connection to Mysql and query is run
- Results retrieved are put on excel Connection to
- mysql closed with VBA

The above process takes in general 0-2 seconds. Records retrieved <100.
Everthing runs fine so far.

In order to be able to connect more people in future, I would like to have some feedback on whether it is ok to continously connect and disconnect from mysql in the way I am doing.
Can it cause some type of crash/memory leaks, etc ??

Is there some better way to do this?

I am hoping to get <2000 users, but I understand the more users connected, worse it is. 
By disconnecting after each search/insert, I am hoping to keep the number of live connections as low as possible.

thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

This constant connecting and disconnecting is an expensive process.

A better way would be to use server-side scripting to manage your connections. This way you would have a single persistent connection to each server, and the users will execute their queries through the single connection. You will also need to implement some sort of job queue for execution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for input.
Could you please direct me to some reading articles about the process you advice to use? 
I've search the internet but couldn't find anything that makes sense.

Comment: You can look at this link - this seems to be similar to what you are trying to do - http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/discussions/88-192809